# Search list from another list in a sequence(not necessarily same order)

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have a list say:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
```

and

```
l2 = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
```

I ran an algorithm on `l2` and got `l1` as the output (I ran prefix scan algorithm which is a sequential pattern mining).
Now my task is to identify the reverse of it, ie) from `[0,1,2]`, I have to identify whether `l2` has that pattern or not.

Initially I tried the index part by calculating the index of l1 and comparing but it will fail since 1,2 is appearing even before 0.

Any idea how we solve this problem?

Input:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
l2 = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
```

Desired output:

```
l2 contains l1 (since 0, 1, 2 is present in l2)
```

Note: though 2,1 are appearing even before but we have to check if after 0 we see 1,2 in any way

Comment: Do the elements of `l1` have to be sequential in `l2`?

Comment: yes!
eg: if l3 = [2,1,0,4,3]
then l1 is not in l3..  like that

Comment: I'm confused. How is `l1` "in" `l2` but not "in" `l3`? Does the order matter or not? Which values are matched between `l1` and `l2`? Specifically, which `1` and which `2` are matched, since `l2` has two of each of these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order matters, but not contiguity, the simplest approach is to look for each element in order:

```
searchidx = 0
try:
    for elem in l1:
        searchidx = l2.index(elem, searchidx) + 1
except ValueError:
    # ... action to take when not found
else:
    # ... action to take when found
```

`list.index` is helpful here by letting you resume your search immediately after the last element found without slicing or rechecking elements you've already searched.

---

If order doesn't matter, just convert one or both inputs to `set`s (or a `collections.Counter` if duplicates might exist in one or both inputs, and counts must be accounted for), and check if `l1`'s `set` is a subset of `l2`'s `set` (or reversing it, if `l2` is a superset of `l1`):

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
l2 = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
s1 = set(l1)
s2 = set(l2)
if s1 <= s2:  # Or s1.issubset(l2) (or s2), or s2 >= s1, or s2.issuperset(l1) (or s1)
    print("l2 contains all the elements of l1")
```

From a performance perspective, probably the most efficient approach for a one-time test is:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
l2 = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
if set(l1).issubset(l2):
    print("l2 contains all the elements of l1")
```

as it minimizes the size of the temporary `set`, and could conceivably short-circuit without testing all of `l2` (depends on how it's implemented).

Comment: set won't work since i have to see if the sequence exists in the list or not. adding set will ignore that order

Comment: @AkshatShreemali: Your title says "not necessarily same order", which I interpreted as "order doesn't matter", but if it's just "not necessarily contiguous", I've added an efficient solution for that requirement too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was able to use your answer and implement the solution. I referred to the list index logic and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to check if elements in `l1` are subset of `l2`

```
set(l1) <= set(l2)
```

Comment: adding set will ignore the order of the list.

Comment: yes, it is what you wrote in the title ("not necessarily in the same order")

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) or implement a [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm yourself. You could then check that the LCS has the same length of the shortest sequence, say l1, to conclude that it is contained in l2.

Comment: I am looking into this as well

Answer (score 0):

Your title says that order doesn't matter, but your description implies that the order *does* matter, but the elements do not have to be contiguous.  In the latter case, find each element in sequence, continuing the search in the remainder of the list:

```
order = [0, 1, 2]
full = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
part = full[:]

for val in order:
    if val in part:
        part = part[part.index(val)+1:]   # This is the step I think you're missing.
        print (val, "found", part)
    else:
        print("Sequencing failed")
        break
```

Output (with trace):

```
0 found [1, 3, 2]
1 found [3, 2]
2 found []
```

Comment: This involves `O(m*n)` work, since it must repeatedly slice the input (`m` times, where `m` is the length of `order`, doing `n` work, where `n` is the length of `full`) to perform the work. You can achieve this with strict `O(n)` work via [`list.index` with a start parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258403/364696), that scans the `list` from an offset without slicing. [ParkerD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258497/364696) achieves the same effect by implementing the item-by-item search manually, which is `O(n)`, but likely slower as it does all the work at the Python layer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but this does what you want I think:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]

l2 = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]
l3 = [2, 1, 0, 4, 3]


def contains(arr, sequence):
    seq_index = 0
    for element in arr:
        try:
            if element == sequence[seq_index]:
                seq_index += 1
        except IndexError:
            break
    return seq_index == len(sequence)


assert contains(l2, l1)
assert not contains(l3, l1)
```

`contains` here will loop through the array given, stepping to the next item in the sequence every time it sees the next one it's looking for. Then it will return `True` if it got through the whole sequence.

Comment: Apologies to everyone.
I confused with my title and the description.
not in same order i meant that though its a sequence, the values can appear even before it.
that is why using set won't work.